# For a polynomial function representing cos(nx), why does the graph fit in a unit square in the interval [-1,1]?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, polynomials

I was doing this question on polynomials:
Let Tn be the polynomial which expresses cos nθ as a function of cos θ, ie.
cos nθ = Tn(cos θ).
Plot T3 and T4 on the interval [−1, 1].
And explain why these fit in a unit square for all n

And I am curious about why that is the case. My thoughts are as follows: is it because of the coefficient of the highest order which is given by $2^{n-1}$ that "squishes" the graph to fit in the unit square? A thing that I had noticed is that the polynomials have a min/max value of -1 and 1 like cos in that range (the only difference being that outside [-1,1] the polynomial tends to \infty - does that have something to do with it?

P.S: T3 = 4$x^3$ - 3x;
T4 = 8$x^4$ - 8$x^2$ + 1
Links to graphs: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/fj3ivt70m7

Comment: Every $x$ in $[-+,1]$ may be written as $x=\cos \theta$ for some $\theta$. So $T_n(x)=\cos(n\theta)\in [-1,1]$.

Comment: @JensSchwaiger something that I had noticed is that Tn(x) graph is not the same as the cos(n$\theta$) - that threw me off a little so I don't completely understand the statement. Can you explain it to me please :)

Comment: $T_n (x)=\cos(n \cos^{-1}(x))$.

Comment: @JensSchwaiger I understand how they are linked but how does this link to the fact that it fits in a unit square?

Comment: Because $-1\leq \cos(y)\leq 1$ for all real $y$.